# Recursive locking in Go

Tags: go

Go's `sync` package has a `Mutex`. Unfortunately it's not recursive. What's the best way to implement recursive locks in Go?

Comment: [Here are Russ Cox's, core Go team member, thoughts on recursive locks](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/XqW1qcuZgKg/Ui3nQkeLV80J). He doesn't like them!

Comment: I created a library that does allow for counting/recursive locks. Give it a try: github.com/jwells131313/goethe

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'm sorry to not answer your question directly:

IMHO, the best way how to implement recursive locks in Go is to not implement them, but rather redesign your code to not need them in the first place. It's probable, I think, that the desire for them indicates a wrong approach to some (unknown here) problem is being used.

As an indirect "proof" of the above claim: Would a recursive lock be a common/correct approach to the/some usual situations involving mutexes, it would be sooner or later included in the standard library.

And finally, last but not least: What Russ Cox from the Go development team wrote here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/XqW1qcuZgKg/Ui3nQkeLV80J:

> Recursive (aka reentrant) mutexes are a bad idea.
>   The fundamental reason to use a mutex is that mutexes
>   protect invariants, perhaps internal invariants like
>   "p.Prev.Next == p for all elements of the ring", or perhaps
>   external invariants like "my local variable x is equal to p.Prev."
>
> Locking a mutex asserts "I need the invariants to hold"
>   and perhaps "I will temporarily break those invariants."
>   Releasing the mutex asserts "I no longer depend on those
>   invariants" and "If I broke them, I have restored them."
>
> Understanding that mutexes protect invariants is essential to
>   identifying where mutexes are needed and where they are not.
>   For example, does a shared counter updated with atomic
>   increment and decrement instructions need a mutex?
>   It depends on the invariants.  If the only invariant is that
>   the counter has value i - d after i increments and d decrements,
>   then the atmocity of the instructions ensures the
>   invariants; no mutex is needed.  But if the counter must be
>   in sync with some other data structure (perhaps it counts
>   the number of elements on a list), then the atomicity of
>   the individual operations is not enough.  Something else,
>   often a mutex, must protect the higher-level invariant.
>   This is the reason that operations on maps in Go are not
>   guaranteed to be atomic: it would add expense without
>   benefit in typical cases.
>
> Let's take a look at recursive mutexes.
>   Suppose we have code like this:

```
     func F() {
             mu.Lock()
             ... do some stuff ...
             G()
             ... do some more stuff ...
             mu.Unlock()
     }

     func G() {
             mu.Lock()
             ... do some stuff ...
             mu.Unlock()
     }
```

> Normally, when a call to mu.Lock returns, the calling code
>   can now assume that the protected invariants hold, until
>   it calls mu.Unlock.
>
> A recursive mutex implementation would make G's mu.Lock
>   and mu.Unlock calls be no-ops when called from within F
>   or any other context where the current thread already holds mu.
>   If mu used such an implementation, then when mu.Lock
>   returns inside G, the invariants may or may not hold.  It depends
>   on what F has done before calling G.  Maybe F didn't even realize
>   that G needed those invariants and has broken them (entirely
>   possible, especially in complex code).
>
> Recursive mutexes do not protect invariants.
>   Mutexes have only one job, and recursive mutexes don't do it.
>
> There are simpler problems with them, like if you wrote

```
     func F() {
             mu.Lock()
             ... do some stuff
     }
```

> you'd never find the bug in single-threaded testing.
>   But that's just a special case of the bigger problem,
>   which is that they provide no guarantees at all about
>   the invariants that the mutex is meant to protect.
>
> If you need to implement functionality that can be called
>   with or without holding a mutex, the clearest thing to do
>   is to write two versions.  For example, instead of the above G,
>   you could write:

```
     // To be called with mu already held.
     // Caller must be careful to ensure that ...
     func g() {
             ... do some stuff ...
     }

     func G() {
             mu.Lock()
             g()
             mu.Unlock()
     }
```

> or if they're both unexported, g and gLocked.
>
> I am sure that we'll need TryLock eventually; feel free to
>   send us a CL for that.  Lock with timeout seems less essential
>   but if there were a clean implementation (I don't know of one)
>   then maybe it would be okay.  Please don't send a CL that
>   implements recursive mutexes.
>
> Recursive mutexes are just a mistake, nothing more than
>   a comfortable home for bugs.
>
> Russ

Comment: An alternative pattern (when needing to provide synchronization) might be to use Go channels.  [Here is an introduction](http://www.golang-book.com/10/index.htm).

Comment: Your "proof" begs the question: Erik has a problem recursive locking might solve, but it's not yet available in the standard library. We don't need to add support, because if it were needed, it'd sooner or later be added.

Comment: This motivation is so off. It is not the mutex responsibility to preserve the invariants. Its responsibility is to prevent mutual access (and the name says it all) at the time invariants are broken. It is your responsibility to make sure that invariants are preserved when the mutex is unlocked, as it is your responsibility in case of a recursive mutex to make sure the invariants are intact when moving from method to method, because ... it is not the mutex responsibility.

Comment: I created a library that does allow for counting/recursive locks.  Give it a try: https://github.com/jwells131313/goethe

Comment: Assume a general purpose library providing function `func F(callback func())`, which locks a mutex and then calls the callback. Of course `callback` is not allowed to call `F` again. But if user by accident does? Deadlock. Rather difficult to discover, if other go routines are still running. A recursive mutex might be used to detect this situation easily and then panic instead (which Go's mutex doesn't do), immediately making the problem obvious to the user.

Comment: Go's `defer` clause which should be used for unlocks is what creates the need for an reentrant lock in the first place, because with that I'm not allowed to call an unlock manually at any other place in the method (or the `defer` clause will panic). So a methods which reads something with a rlock and in some cases delegates to another method to write something with a wlock won't work, I have to choose between a deadlock or a panic due to a double unlock (manual unlock + `defer` unlock) here.

Comment: @NotX You CAN call unlock in another place then lock again, if needed. The *locked methods are the way you do it.

Comment: @PaulStelian Might be a misunderstanding. My issue is not the re-usabilty of locks
in a successive manner (i.e. lock-unlock, lock-unlock), but that locks might get unlocked twice, once "manually" in a conditional clause, and once in the `defer` clause (i.e. lock-unlock-unlock).

Comment: @NotX I usually just do unlock, recursive call, then lock again so that the defer clause has something to unlock. Yes, it's a bit weird, but it can be done. And of course the simpler option of having *locked functions that don't do anything on their own, that just works.

Comment: Recursive mutexes are common, e.g., VxWorks, Posix.

Comment: Downvote. The answer is incomplete and not helpful. The problems described by Russ Cox are theoretical, they hardly matter in practice. But there are scenarios (usually involving callbacks, recursion, etc.) that are very hard or impossible to implement with non-reentrant locks. In Java and C#, locks are reentrant. POSIX, Python and many others offer reentrant locks. Russ Cox seems to think the designers of all of these languages and libraries are wrong. I'd say Russ Cox's thinking about this question is too simplistic.

Answer (score 6):

You could quite easily make a recursive lock out of a [sync.Mutex](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) and a [sync.Cond](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Cond).  See [Appendix A here](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/TechNotes/ThreadSafeLibrary.html) for some ideas.

**Except** for the fact that the Go runtime doesn't expose any notion of goroutine Id.  This is to stop people doing silly things with goroutine local storage, and probably indicates that the designers think that if you need a goroutine Id you are doing it wrong.

You can of course [dig the goroutine Id out of the runtime with a bit of C](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/Nt0hVV_nqHE/9Qj8zRlZWZ4J) if you really want to.  You might want to read that thread to see why the designers of Go think it is a bad idea.

Answer (score -14):

as was already established, this is a miserable, horrible, awful, and terrible idea from a concurrency perspective.

Anyway, since your question is really about Go's type system, here's how you would define a type with a recursive method.

```
type Foo struct{}

func (f Foo) Bar() { fmt.Println("bar") }

type FooChain struct {
    Foo
    child *FooChain
}

func (f FooChain) Bar() {
    if f.child != nil {
        f.child.Bar()
    }
    f.Foo.Bar()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("no children")
    f := new(FooChain)
    f.Bar()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        f = &FooChain{Foo{}, f}
    }
    fmt.Println("with children")
    f.Bar()
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/mPBHKpgxnd

Comment: I guess then all languages that support recursive locks (and that's most of them) are miserable, horrible, awful and terrible.

Comment: not necessarily, it's just terrible with regards to managing concurrency in Go.  What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @ErikAigner locks are just usually slower than other concurrent design constructs.