# what is the golang equivalent of a Java synchronized() block?

Tags: synchronization, go

Java provides a very convenient idiom for synchronizing critical portions of code:

```
synchronized(someObject) {
    // do something really important all by myself with nobody bothering me
}
```

Or

```
public synchronized void doSomething() {
    // ...
}
```

What is the go equivalent?

(A quick search reveals: [golang.org/pkg/sync/](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/) - which seems (maybe I'm wrong) a bit too low level for general use.)

(Example of why I care about this: I need to send a message to multiple listeners via channels.  Channels provide a good conduit for the data without having to synchronize anything, but when channels are added or removed I need to modify the list of channels, which might happen at any time must be able to deal with concurrency.)

Answer (score 23):

[sync.Mutex](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) is a mutual exclusion lock, it can provide a similar functionality to the `synchronized` java key-word (except that locks in java provide `reentrant` mutual exclusion) :

```
synchronized(someObject) {
    //   
}
```

Is equivalent to :

```
var l sync.Mutex

l.Lock()
//
l.Unlock()
```

Comment: The semantics aren't the same. Java synchronized blocks provide re-entrant locks.

Comment: Yeah, you are right @Anonymous ,but  `Go` don't have `java-like ` class inheritance, so I believe that there is no need for a `reentrant locks` in `Go`.

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/jfeBxkve65 would work in Java, but deadlocks in Go. Inheritance plays no part.

Comment: Some discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670979/recursive-locking-in-go

Comment: For my application I do not need reentrance (and IMO this would be the most common scenario), so this would work.

Answer (score 16):

to extend off tarrsalah's answer.

You can add sync.Mutex to your object, allowing them to be directly locked and unlocked.

```
type MyObject struct{
    Number int
    sync.Mutex
}

func (m *MyObject)Increment(){
    m.Lock()
    defer m.Unlock()
    m.Number++
}
```

Defer'd commands will run at the end of the function, this way you know it gets both locked and unlocked, in bigger functions.

Comment: This answer is better because it mentions defer. Calling unlock()  manually is prone to deadlocks

Answer (score 9):

A different solution to using a mutex is to use a channel to communicate listener changes.

A full example in this style looks like this. The interesting code is in FanOuter.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Message int

type ListenerUpdate struct {
    Add      bool
    Listener chan Message
}

// FanOuter maintains listeners, and forwards messages from msgc
// to each of them. Updates on listc can add or remove a listener.
func FanOuter(msgc chan Message, listc chan ListenerUpdate) {
    lstrs := map[chan Message]struct{}{}
    for {
        select {
        case m := <-msgc:
            for k := range lstrs {
                k <- m
            }
        case lup := <-listc:
            if lup.Add {
                lstrs[lup.Listener] = struct{}{}
            } else {
                delete(lstrs, lup.Listener)
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    msgc := make(chan Message)
    listc := make(chan ListenerUpdate)
    go FanOuter(msgc, listc)
    // Slowly add listeners, then slowly remove them.
    go func() {
        chans := make([]chan Message, 10)
        // Adding listeners.
        for i := range chans {
            chans[i] = make(chan Message)
            // A listener prints its id and any messages received.
            go func(i int, c chan Message) {
                for {
                    m := <-c
                    fmt.Printf("%d received %d\n", i, m)
                }
            }(i, chans[i])
            listc <- ListenerUpdate{true, chans[i]}
            time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
        }
        // Removing listeners.
        for i := range chans {
            listc <- ListenerUpdate{false, chans[i]}
            time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    // Every second send a message to the fanouter.
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("About to send ", i)
        msgc <- Message(i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really good answer as it don't simply translate a lock from java to go, it uses go to resolve the initial problem you have with concurrency. It also clearly answers the problem stated .. +1