# Detect the same goroutine calling sync.Mutex.Lock() twice in a row

Tags: go, locking, mutex, reentrancy

This code (a single threaded program) will never work:

```
func TestDoubleLockPanics(t *testing.T) {
    var mu sync.Mutex
    mu.Lock()
    mu.Lock()
}
```

However, when I run this test, there's no panic. The race detector does not print out a data race. `go vet` does not complain, there's no log message, it just blocks forever.

(The actual real-life code I care about is, obviously, not this simple - I've just boiled it down to the essence.)

Is there any way to get Go to tell me, loudly, when a thread that holds a lock attempts to re-acquire the same lock?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14670979/1256452

Answer (score 5):

Go's `sync.Mutex` objects do not keep track of which goroutine locked them.  Or, to put it another way, there *isn't* a locking thread: there is just a data lock.

Moreover, as the comment just above [`Unlock`](https://golang.org/src/sync/mutex.go?s=5772:5796#L165) says, you can unlock them from some other goroutine than the one that locked them.  Hence it can actually make sense to call `Lock` twice.  Here's a skeleton example:

```
func f() {
    mu.Lock()
    ... if this is not just an example, some code goes here ...
    // now wait for g() to call mu.Unlock()
    mu.Lock()
    fmt.Println("we got here, so g() must have done an unlock")
    mu.Unlock()
}

func g() {
    ... some code probably goes here too ...
    mu.Unlock() // allow f() to proceed
    ... more code, perhaps ...
}
```

In this case we would not want a panic in `f`'s second `Lock` call.

You can build your own recursive locks or other techniques, but since the internal ID of each goroutine is hidden, it's [pretty tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14673524/1256452).  There's a link to [an implementation](https://github.com/jwells131313/goethe) in the comments at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14671462/1256452) to [Recursive locking in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14670979/1256452), but I've never used it, or even looked closely at it.